# Getting error Field "cover" must not have a selection since type "String" has no subfields when deploy

Tags: graphql, gatsby, gatsby-plugin

I am getting error when deploy on netlify:

> 10:49:33 AM: error There was an error in your GraphQL query: 10:49:33
> AM: Field "cover" must not have a selection since type "String" has no
> subfields. 10:49:33 AM: This can happen if you e.g. accidentally added
> { } to the field "cover". If you didn't expect "cover" to be of type
> "String" make sure that your input source and/or plugin is correct.
> failed extract queries from components - 0.355s

Here is my following code:

```
export const pageQuery = graphql`
  {
    hero: allMarkdownRemark(filter: { fileAbsolutePath: { regex: "/hero/" } }) {
      edges {
        node {
          frontmatter {
            title
            name
            subtitle
            buttonText
          }
          html
        }
      }
    }
    about: allMarkdownRemark(filter: { fileAbsolutePath: { regex: "/about/" } }) {
      edges {
        node {
          frontmatter {
            title
            avatar {
              childImageSharp {
                fluid(maxWidth: 700, quality: 90, traceSVG: { color: "#64ffda" }) {
                  ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_withWebp_tracedSVG
                  base64
                }
              }
            }
            skills
          }
          html
        }
      }
    }
    jobs: allMarkdownRemark(
      filter: { fileAbsolutePath: { regex: "/jobs/" } }
      sort: { fields: [frontmatter___date], order: DESC }
    ) {
      edges {
        node {
          frontmatter {
            title
            company
            location
            range
            url
          }
          html
        }
      }
    }
    featured: allMarkdownRemark(
      filter: { fileAbsolutePath: { regex: "/featured/" } }
      sort: { fields: [frontmatter___date], order: DESC }
    ) {
      edges {
        node {
          frontmatter {
            title
            cover {
              childImageSharp {
                fluid(maxWidth: 700, quality: 90, traceSVG: { color: "#64ffda" }) {
                  ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_withWebp_tracedSVG
                  base64
                }
              }
            }
            tech
            github
            external
          }
          html
        }
      }
    }
    projects: allMarkdownRemark(
      filter: {
        fileAbsolutePath: { regex: "/projects/" }
        frontmatter: { showInProjects: { ne: false } }
      }
      sort: { fields: [frontmatter___date], order: DESC }
    ) {
      edges {
        node {
          frontmatter {
            title
            tech
            github
            external
          }
          html
        }
      }
    }
    contact: allMarkdownRemark(filter: { fileAbsolutePath: { regex: "/contact/" } }) {
      edges {
        node {
          frontmatter {
            title
            buttonText
          }
          html
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

I tried to add base64 like people said when I try to search for a solution but it still giving me this error. How can I fix it?

Comment: Does it build locally?

Answer (score 0):

```
frontmatter {
        title
        cover {
          childImageSharp {
            fluid(maxWidth: 700, quality: 90, traceSVG: { color: "#64ffda" }) {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_withWebp_tracedSVG
              base64
            }
          }
        }
        tech
        github
        external
      }
```

In this code snippet the field **cover** is of **String** type, not an **object**. In graphql you can not sub select for primitive data types like int, string, id, etc. So you can not access **childImageSharp** in cover. Check the structure of API or fix it from the back-end. Here,

```
frontmatter {
    title
    cover 
    tech
    github
    external
  }
```

this will work

Comment: It's giving me this error `Field "cover" of type "File" must have a selection of subfields. Did you mean "cover { ... }"?`

Comment: But in the above error, it was saying "cover" is of type String but now it is file. If that's the can then cover is a object and it must have sub-selection like the original code

Comment: In the snippet above `cover` is an **object**